# Loop for combination python

Tags: python, loops

I need a loop for combination of for example:
i got 2 lists:

```
list = [1,2,3]
combiantion_list = [(1), (2), (3), (1,2), (2,3), (1,3), (1,2,3)]
```

I want to a loop to get to all these lists in my combination_list, for example:

```
combination_list[0][0]
combination_list[1][0]
combination_list[2][0]
combination_list[3][0]
combination_list[3][1]
etc...
```

Comment: Can you please include the expected output?

Comment: I just need to loop through these combination_list (including lists in that list)

Answer (score 2):

You are after something like this:

```
for i in combiniation_list:
    for j in i:
        #do what you want with j
```

If you have any specific questions as to how it works, let me know.

```
>>> combination_list = [(1,2),(3,4)]
>>> for i in combination_list:
...     for j in i:
...             print(j)
...
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: If i do that, it doesnt enter the inside (for instance : it gives me (1,2), (2,3) as well - imo i want to get inside these lists also)

Comment: @MateuszSawicki You must be doing something wrong. It sounds like you are using i, instead of j in the inner loop. I edited my post with an example so you can see how it works in action.

Comment: Okej its working ;) my bad i guess
But the other question is, how what kind of loop i need to do to achieve connection with [0][0], [1][0] etc, so i can get exceptions on lists inside (cuz ill hold methods in that lists)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
list(chain.from_iterable(combinations([1,2,3], x) for x in xrange(3)))
```

Comment: Did you mean to `import combinations`  `from itertools` too?

Comment: That's the `powerset` with the `()` element removed. How sad is it that the functions listed in https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes aren't part of the module proper.

Comment: @DanD. thanks, didn't know. I guess because itertools is very minimalistic module and powerset is derivative function.

Answer (score 0):

I got the combination_list already... All i need now is to get through all those elements inside that combination_list (including lists inside - for example: not giving (1,2), (1,3), (2,3) -> i want also to get inside these lists)